# How to add variable in find() on pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have below document structure on my DB.
[Doc]

{
  "device" : "ABC",
  "extra" : "dddd"
}

I have tried to find function like below.

deviceName = "ABC"

doc.find({'device': "'" + deviceName + "'"})

But I have still attribute error.
Could you give some advice for this, please?

Comment: `doc.find({ 'device': deviceName })` No need for quotes, it's already a string. What error?

Comment: I have tried, too. it still happen this exception <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>

Comment: I think you are actually getting that error from code that comes "after" the `.find()` here. Point is that you are not showing the code where the error actually occurs. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44536864/edit) to include the full context.

Comment: Yes, you are right. find() call was ok. however, 
data = doc.find({'device': "'" + deviceName + "'"}).size() <== this gonna happen exception. I am not sure how to check return type.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
doc[deviceName]
```

Or, if you're not certain that the key is in your document, then:

```
doc.get(deviceName)
```

... which will return None if the key is absent.